# Is there a good reference online for Class Methods , depreciation for all versions?

Tags: magento-1.9

With so many different versions of magento around , is there a really good reference / tool for classes , methods etc spanning across versions?

I found [This page](https://makandracards.com/magento/25033-magento-version-history) which gives you an overall history of magento and repositories for all versions - but it is cumbersome to wade through everything.

I would even pay for a good book! ( preferably a quick reference ) .  I have alan Storms "No frills layout" book which is very helpful - but looking for something more.

Some of the things I want to do:

- know which class methods are deprecated / introduced through versions
- know which core attributes are deprecated / introduced over the versions.
- Syntax / methods that are synonymous - and if there are performance differences ( e.g. count vs getSize or the different ways of instantiating classes as an object ).

Note:  I don't want the api reference , I think the things I need are more low level. It seems to me that the magento documentation is significantly lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking several questions in one, in my opinion.  I think you may be seeking something that isn't exactly documented somewhere, but rather a series of concepts that could be partly defined as the Magento framework itself.

---

There are a few tips I think you should consider...

1) Use PHPStorm with Magicento plug-in.  Understand all the functionality that Magicento brings to the table, and how it simplifies development.

2) Use n98-magerun and search for plug-ins to assist with generation of getters and setters documentation within the code.

3) Understand the magic methods: **get, set, has** and then understand how overrides to magic methods are applied.. for example, that `public function get<Anything>` is overriding the magic method.  Understand the setData() and getData() methods... etc.

4) Understand the framework of Magento, but primarily how the framework is actually used within code of Magento's modules.  What I mean by this, is to search Magento code for usage of itself.  Ie: instead of using PHP functions, search for what magento would use instead -- the wrapper functions.  `Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php` would be an example of wrapper functions available to all helper classes... You will see functions such as:

- `htmlEscape()` - @deprecated after 1.4.0.0-rc1, is now wrapper to escapeHtml()
- `escapeHtml()` - Escape html entities

Then searching the core code and templates for 'escapeHtml` will show how they are used and where.

Additional examples would be the 'core/string' helper class, the basic 'core' helper - `Mage::helper('core')`

Here's an example list of some wrapper functions I've found used in the code:

- `Mage::app()->getCookie()->delete(self::COOKIE_CURRENCY, $code);`
- `Mage::app()->getCookie()->set(self::COOKIE_CURRENCY, $code);`
- `Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode()`
- `Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode()`
- `Mage::helper('core')->removeAccents(...)`
- `Mage::helper('core')->formatCurrency($value, $includeContainer = true)`
- `Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(...)`
- `Mage::helper('core')->formatTime(...)`
- `Mage::helper('core')->encrypt(...)`
- `Mage::helper('core')->decrypt(...)`
- `Mage::helper('core')->unEscapeCSVData($data)`
- `Mage::helper('core')->getEscapedCSVData(array $data)`
- `Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->getUrl($routePath = null, $routeParams = null)`
- `Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d');`
- `Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s')`
- `Mage::helper('core')`
- `Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr()`
- `Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpHost()`

5) Alessandro Ronchi wrote quite an excellent resource called: Magento Best Practices and is available: https://leanpub.com/magebp/
It is one of the most straight-forward resources for proper development.  It gives examples of what would be better performing code, and which performance hindering code to avoid.

---

I am almost certain that phpDocumentor will generate the deprecation information that you seek:
https://www.phpdoc.org/

For example, searching globally in the `app/code/core/` directory for all the lines containing **@deprecated**, you'll get an insight into what would be compiled into the output of phpDocumentor.

If you search for all the @deprecated elements in the doc blocks of Magento, you will get lines such as:

> @deprecated since 1.7.0.2. Refactored and moved to Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Rewrite
>   @deprecated after 1.5.1.0 - mistake in method name
>   @deprecated after 1.3.2.4

---

Hopefully this is a good starting point.  Perhaps what has made Magento so difficult, is the fact that there are all these special quirks and "hidden secrets" that ultimately can differentiate PHP developers from "Magento" developers.  Magento developers, in my opinion, are experience-driven developers that have harvested and collected the little bits of knowledge needed to use the framework properly and effectively.

---

**Final Answer**

Start with #5 - The book written by Alessandro Ronchi -

> "Magento Best Practices Handbook" - A collection of practical advices to develop with Magento the right way.

https://leanpub.com/magebp/

The book will explain essential tools and resources to get you going, then move forward with essential knowledge for excellent development.

Comment: Wow , thank you - that is SO helpful.  I have a webstorm license .. so I will take a look. shame they don't have the plugin for VS code.   I'll get the book.  this is all gold .. and much appreciated!

Comment: Webstorm !== phpStorm,  so, a free trial of PHPStorm should suffice for now.  Also, if you are serious about Magento development, I don't think there really is an IDE that can compete with PHPStorm.

Comment: A right thanks.. yes I have a jetbrains subscription.. one of the other devs here was using it .. but it's not being used now so I'll give it a shot.   I'm on windows but I can load another box ( VM or  PC )  - is it "less painful"  with another OS?

Comment: I am using Windows, as well.  I use powershell CLI and can do practically anything that I could do within the linux command line.